# Using Vue JS in Smarty template - question about :src

Tags: javascript, vue.js, smarty

I use a Vue JS application and a smarty template. Currently I have this issue:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#bpRequestModal',

    data: {
        productImage: 'test.jpg',
    },
```

In my template I use this:

```
{literal}
<img :src="productImage" />
{/literal}
```

But, when I use `:src` the whole app `#bpRequestModal` is removed from the DOM. I also tried `<img src="{{ productImage }}"` but then I do see just this "productImage" in my DOM. I also tried `:src={$productImage}` without success.

Does anybody know how I can get `'test.jpg'` in my img src?

Answer (score 0):

looks like you seem to just mention the file name without relative folder path.

`productImage: 'test.jpg'`

should'nt it be with relative path like below if its in same folder as the vue file

`productImage: './test.jpg'`

Comment: in the end, sure it will be another path, but that doesn't matter here, right? I just want to see that vue replaces the variable with the value from my data element.

Comment: that is true, it should at least replace the variable value. Unsure why it is not doing that, i tried exactly the same as yours and it did replace the value correctly though image did not render. Sorry couldnt be of much help.